# Locale to use for lowercasing HTTP values in Java

Tags: java, string, locale

When a user's default locale is turkish, `i` gets lowercased to `ı`. This is problematic because I want to include my user's language and country codes in my `Accept-Language` header, but [`OkHttp` only allows ASCII header values](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016). I realize that `Accept-Language` has historically been case-insensitive, but I have to interact with a server that I don't own that expects lowercase-only `Accept-Language` header values. What locale should I use for machine-only lowercasing like this?

Comment: Whatever any software does for headers generally, the _standards_ limit language-range in Accept-language to only ASCII letters and digits, hyphen, and asterisk. And (the letters in it) are always case-insensitive, so why do you want to lowercase?

Comment: The server I have to interact with expects it to be lowercase. I don't control that server.

Comment: Also, non-ascii characters are allowed in the original HTTP/1.1 spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.2

Comment: And in the updated HTTP/1.1 spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4

Comment: From the updated: Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only through use of [RFC2047] encoding. In practice, most HTTP header field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII]. Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to US-ASCII octets. A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field content (obs-text) as opaque data.

Comment: Historically different headers have varied in the chars allowerd, but _Accept-language specifically_ has always been explicitly and clearly case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any official Java documentation talking about guaranteed machine-invariant lowercasing behavior.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)  talks about an `en_US_POSIX`:

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is `en_US_POSIX`, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. `en_US_POSIX` is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but `en_US_POSIX` will not), and between platforms (`en_US_POSIX` works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms).

`en_US_POSIX` is available in Java with `new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX")`. I don't know how guaranteed this is.